# Calculate number of rows in an Oracle query

Tags: oracle, count, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a simple way to get the number of rows an Oracle SQL query returns?

I tried `count` in various ways but none worked. This seems to do the trick

```
SELECT   ROWNUM, mv.*
FROM    my_view mv
where col_a IS NOT NULL
order by ROWNUM desc
```

but is there something straightforward like `nrow` in R or `.shape` in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was just wondering what the best practice would be to check the size of the view (...) I don't need to display the entire view, but only need to know the number of rows.

In that case, `count(*)` seems to be *the way* to do it. Pure & simple

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM my_view
WHERE col_a IS NOT NULL;
```

(You used `order by` clause; it *promises* to be slower than query without it.)

---

Alternatively, if it were a **table** (not a view), you could use a *really fast* option - query `user_tables`:

```
SQL> SELECT num_rows
  2    FROM user_tables
  3   WHERE table_name = 'EVID';

  NUM_ROWS
----------
    808757
```

How many rows does that table really have?

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT (*) FROM evid;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    808761

SQL>
```

Not *exactly* the same. Why? Because you should gather statistics:

```
SQL> EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('SJERV', 'EVID');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Now those values match:

```
SQL> SELECT num_rows
  2    FROM user_tables
  3   WHERE table_name = 'EVID';

  NUM_ROWS
----------
    808761

SQL>
```

It just means that you should regularly gather (schema) statistics - for example, on a daily basis. Then you'd have pretty much close information about number of rows. But, to be *sure* how many rows you really have, once again - `select count(*)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   count(*) over () as row_count, mv.*
FROM    my_view mv
where col_a IS NOT NULL
```

will give you a count but unless you can be sure that performance is not going to be a problem, its generally a bad idea to do this.  Because what if the table has 1 billion rows and you only need to show the first (say) 200 rows on screen?  We are going to visit all the candidate rows in order to work out that count.

That's why a Google search says "Results 1..20 of ABOUT ..."

Comment: Hi Connor, thanks for the answer. That was a good advice. However, I was just wondering what the best practice would be to check the size of the view, for example, when you have to cross-reference the size of the query to another source. That is, I don't need to display the entire view, but only need to know the number of rows.

Comment: For any given query, simply doing   "select count(*) from ( your query )" will give the number of rows that will come back.....but try not to do that :-)

Comment: Hi Connor, thanks for your reply. May I ask why it's not encouraged?

Comment: To show people the total number of rows is asking for trouble down the track as your table gets larger.  They'll complain when you're forced to remove it when it becomes inpractical to count them